# Issue with the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application in `Android Studio` I have been trying for days to remove the `ActionBar`. I don't know why is always shown though I changed the default `Theme`.
I have had this issue since I updated `Android Studio` to the `3.6.0 version`. 
Can you help me please?
This is my `manifest`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.ultimate.app.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    </application>
```

this is my `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar"/>

</resources>
```

**EDIT**
`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("");


    tab1.setIndicator("Home");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class));


    tab2.setIndicator("Preferiti");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

    tab3.setIndicator("Altro");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

and this is what I always have:

[image]

**EDIT**
updated `manifest`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity
        android:name="com.ultimate.app.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    </application>
```

Comment: please show your MainActivity.java, if you do not want to use an ActionBar you should simply not extend `ActionBarActivity` instead just extend `Activity`

Comment: As you can see in my edit I'm not extending `ActionBarActivity` in my `MainActivity` and so in my other activities I have too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in the style.xml in the folder values:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
```

And for each API level you change the base creating a folder 'values-vXX' where 'XX' is the API level. For example:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
```

In your manifest:

```
<android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

The style.xml in the folder values, sets the theme for the target API level.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your application is not using the theme that you set in your style.xml. My guess is that you are not changing the app theme in the right place. Check it please.

Comment: What? I'm using it in `<application.../>`